# How to calculate the median of a masked tensor along an axis?

Tags: pytorch

I have tensor `X` of floats of dimensions `n x m` and a tensor `Y` of booleans of dimensions `n x m`. I want to calculate values such as the mean, median and max of `X`, along one of the axes, but only considering the values in `X` which are true in `Y`. Something like `X[Y].mean(dim=1)`. This is not possible because `X[Y]` is always a 1D tensor.

**Edit:**

For the mean, I was able to do it with:

```py
masked_X = X * Y
masked_X_mean = masked_X.sum(dim=1) / Y.sum(dim=1)
```

For the max:

```py
masked_X = X
masked_X[Y] = float('-inf')
masked_X_max = masked_X.max(dim=1)
```

But for the median, I was not able to be as creative. Any suggestions??

e.g.

```
X = torch.tensor([[1, 1, 1],
                  [2, 2, 4]]).type(torch.float32)
Y = torch.tensor([[0, 1, 0],
                  [1, 0, 1]]).type(torch.bool)
```

Expected Output

```
mean = [1., 3.]
median = [1., 2.]
var = [0., 1.]
```

Comment: May be if you could tell what other statistics you are calculating, we could help. Otherwise, your mean calculation seems best solution to me.

Comment: @Mohsinhasan the median would be nice, as I have already found a way to ǵet the max.

Comment: Can't think of easy way of doing masked median in pytorch. May be you transfer array to numpy, replace masked values by 'np.nan' and then use 'np.nanmedian' and transfer things back

Answer (score 2):

This is the best I have so far on this:

```
outs = []
for x, y in zip(X, Y):  # X, Y could be permuted to loop over desired axis
    out = torch.median(torch.masked_select(x, y))
    outs.append(out)
torch.tensor(outs)
```

Would really appreciate if someone has better solution.

Answer (score 0):

**Max and median:**

As one of the tensor is boolean, it will be great to do elementwise multiplication of original and mask and then just calculate max/median like this.

```
array = torch.randint(10, (4,4))
mask = torch.randint(2, (4,4)) #it will just generate the [0,1] values]
sol_max = torch.max(array*mask)
sol_median = torch.median(array*mask)
```

Comment: This would not work. For example, if `array` contains only negative values and I use the mask to transform some of the values into `0`, then getting the max of this masked array would give me 0 and not the largest value in the non-masked spots (because they would be negative, and so, smaller than 0). The median would also be affected, since by ordering the masked tensor and getting the mid-point, the 0s could shift where the median would be extracted from.

Answer (score 0):

You can piggyback on [`torch.nanmedian`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nanmedian.html):

```py
def masked_median(x, mask, dim=0):
    """Compute the median of tensor x along dim, ignoring values where mask is False.
    x and mask need to be broadcastable.

    Args:
        x (Tensor): Tensor to compute median of.
        mask (BoolTensor): Same shape as x with True where x is valid and False
            where x should be masked. Mask should not be all False in any column of
            dimension dim to avoid NaNs from zero division.
        dim (int, optional): Dimension to take median of. Defaults to 0.

    Returns:
        Tensor: Same shape as x, except dimension dim reduced.
    """
    # uncomment this assert for safety but might impact performance
    # assert (
    #     mask.sum(dim=dim).ne(0).all()
    # ), "mask should not be all False in any column, causes zero division"
    x_nan = x.float().masked_fill(~mask, float("nan"))
    x_median, _ = x_nan.nanmedian(dim=dim)
    return x_median


X = torch.tensor([[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 4]])
Y = torch.tensor([[0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1]]).bool()

masked_median(X, Y, dim=1)
>>> tensor([1., 2.])
```

Signature with type hints:

```py
def masked_median(x: torch.Tensor, mask: torch.BoolTensor, dim: int = 0) -> torch.Tensor:
    ...
```

Btw, same approach works for `masked_var()`:

```py
def masked_var(x, mask, dim=0):
    x_nan = x.float().masked_fill(~mask, float("nan"))

    nan_mean = x_nan.nanmean(dim=dim, keepdim=True)
    squared_diff = (x_nan - nan_mean) ** 2
    var = squared_diff.nanmean(dim=dim)
    return var

masked_var(X, Y, dim=1)
>>> tensor([0., 1.])
```